# Is it considered as noise to thank authors for their answers?

Tags: discussion

I thank a lot. This is a cultural thing, and I feel uncomfortable with the idea of just anonymously upvoting when people spend quite some time (and sometimes quite an impressive time) to answer my questions.

However, I know this is often considered as noise on the SE model. Is it OK here, or do I need to plug some mental filter in order to maintain the S/N ratio high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! I personally don't mind such comments on questions, but I tend to remove "proactive" thank-yous in the questions themselves.

The system flags items (questions or answers) with excessive comments, but I've never seen it flag for excessive thank-yous. it's usually a full-blown discussion that... probably doesn't belong here.